# WalletConnectv2 Issue for Gnosis-Safe Chain IDs Error

Tags: gnosis-safe, walletconnect, chainid

I'm working with a team to build out a new wallet to connect to Safe with WalletConnectv2. However, I'm getting an error in the backend that it says that you only support `chainID` EIP155:42220 which is CELO when I am attempting to establish a connection with an L1 ETH wallet which should be EIP155:1.

Can someone please explain if this error is on our side or is there an incorrect chainID mapping to ETH within the WalletConnect v2 deployment?